# Settext when you touch on edittex

Tags: android

How settext when you touch the edittext? example When you touch the edittext this delete the text automatically

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/valor"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tipo"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/value"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

The initial value is 0 but when I touch the edittext I need what the value are ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `android:onClick` attribute. Suppose you do this:

```
android:onClick="deleteText"
```

Then you'd need to implement the method like this:

```
public void deleteText(View view) {
  // view will reference to your TextView
  TextView tv = (TextView) view;
  tv.setText("");
}
```

This would erase the text in it at that time.

Comment: The problem with setting the click listener via the XML is that if you then use that layout in a Fragment instead of an Activity, it doesn't work because it still looks in the Activity for the method.  Since the Fragment shouldn't be delegating onClick calls to its Activity, this is a bad way to link the onClick method.  Instead, if you must have an onClick method, you should assign it programatically with `setOnClickListener()` on the view after inflating the XML.

Comment: That assuming that the OP is using Fragments. In this case you're right.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if they are or they are not.  Having just had to convert 37 Activities to Fragments and undoing all the onClick assignments in the XML made it clear that this is a bad idea because one day you'll want to reuse the XML and if you assign the click listener with onClick then it's not as reusable.  All code should be made to be as reusable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint) property.  It displays text in grey until the user starts entering their own text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click listener programmatically.

```
final EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valor);
textBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textBox.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
final EditText editText = (ExitText)findViewById(R.id.valor);
    exitText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    editText.setText("");
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hint rather than doing like so, Just use this line in your EditText of your xml file:

```
android:hint="Write Hint"
```

You can use this concept of selector and when onFocus removes the hint.